# graph api search not returning a post

Tags: search, facebook-graph-api

I am searching using https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=anglogold&type=post
this is not returning a post I made myself just now. Any idea why

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=anglogold&type=post

returns a lot of posts for me.

Facebook can restrict results on search api on different scenarios.

1. Not suitable for a particular country/region
2. Not a public post
3. Person is blocked by user

   and may be few others.

Comment: I've posted this publicly on a friends wall, and it doesn't show, another example, I created this group as open http://www.facebook.com/groups/355154884542602/ but it doesn't return with https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=anglogold&type=group

Comment: im noticing this behavior as well but cannot pinpoint why it works for some users and not others. also seems to sometimes work when posting via mobile rather than desktop.